# android build failed with duplicate class error in build output

Tags: android

This is my build output error.

[image]

and here is my build.gradle.kts file

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
    id("com.google.gms.google-services")
}

android {
    namespace = "com.bwc.shopsaver"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.bwc.shopsaver"
        minSdk = 26
        targetSdk = 30
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "17"
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
    }

}

dependencies {

    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.0")
    implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1")
    implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.11.0")
    implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4")
    implementation("androidx.room:room-compiler-processing-testing:2.6.1")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")

    //splash screen
    implementation ("androidx.core:core-splashscreen:1.1.0-alpha02")



    //Glide for image
    implementation ("com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.16.0")
    annotationProcessor ("com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.16.0")
    // Fragment Navigation
    implementation ("androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.7.6")
    implementation ("androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.7.6")

    //FireBase Authentication
    implementation(platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.7.1"))
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics")
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-database")
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-auth")
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore")



    implementation ("com.google.android.play:integrity:1.3.0")

    // Retrofit
    implementation ("com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0")
    implementation ("com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0")

    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.8.0-RC2")



}
```

the error raised when i start using

```
implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-database")
```

for which it said that minimum sdk shuld be at least 26 then i changed to 26 but after that this error came and i am not able to solve this.
What is the possible error?

it showing a library that i haven't used.

i have tried clean >> rebuild and invalidate cache and restart.

Comment: Do you see this error only after adding the firebase database dependency with all the other dependencies? Or if you remove the firestore dependency and add the database one, then there is no error?